# tensorflow tensorflow.contrib.learn.Estimator load trained model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

After I call this function like this:

```
    from tensorflow.contrib import learn
    #----------------------------------------
    #Do some process here
    #----------------------------------------
    classifier = learn.Estimator(model_fn=bag_of_words_model,model_dir='F:/data')
    classifier.fit(feature_train, target_train, steps=1000)
```

I will have some file in my folder "F:/data" like this 
[image]

And I wonder Do I have anyway to reuse this model ? Like move to new computer and use this to predict new data. Sorry for my bad English. Thanks for all the answers!! Hope you all have a nice day.

Comment: Paste image here kindly

Comment: I don't have enough reputation, sorry for that inconvenient, Can you please help me overcome this problem sir ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a script where you want to reuse your model, redefine/import `bag_of_words_model` again and define

```
classifier_loaded = learn.Estimator(model_fn=bag_of_words_model, model_dir='F:/data')
```

Tensorflow will reload the graph and import the weights into the graph and you can just use it as

```
classifier_loaded.predict(input_fn=input_fn)
```

or continue the training with

```
claissifier_loaded.fit(feature_train, target_train)
```